# Displaying floating point numbers in 16-bit assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

For studies, I have to write a program in TASM x86, which will calculate tangens of x. I wrote this using stack. I've never dealt with ASM before and we were given little time for the project. The program compiles, but i have trouble with displaying a value. Program displays a random signs (I'am guessing, maybe ASCII code). Lecturer gave us a hint that we have to change number into string, but I have no idea how to do it.

Does anybody have any idea, how to do this with any possible way?

Code:

```
.model small
.stack 100h

.data

   result dq 0.0

    x dq 0.5
    two dq 2.0
    three dq 3.0
    fifteen dq 15.0
    seventeen dq 17.0
    three_hundred_fifteen dq 315.0

.code    
    
tan proc    
   ;x^3/3
   fld x
   fld x
   fmulp 
   fld x
   fmulp 
   fld three
   fdivp
   
   ;2x^5/15    
   fld x
   fld x
   fmulp 
   fld x
   fmulp 
   fld x
   fmulp
   fld x
   fmulp ;x^5
   fld two
   fmulp ;2x^5
   fld fifteen
   fdivp

   ;x^3/3 + 2x^5/15
   faddp
   
   ;17x^7/315
   fld x
   fld x
   fmulp 
   fld x
   fmulp 
   fld x
   fmulp
   fld x
   fmulp 
   fld x
   fmulp
   fld x
   fmulp ;x^7    
   fld seventeen    
   fmulp ; 17x^7    
   fld three_hundred_fifteen
   fdivp
   
   ;x^3/3 + 2x^5/15 + 17x^7/315
   faddp       
   ;x
   fld x
   
   ;x + x^3/3 + 2x^5/15 + 17x^7/315    
   faddp       
   fstp result       
   ret       

   tan endp    

start:
    call tan

    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, offset result
    int 21h
    
end start
```

I search all over the internet, I tried using AI, but nothing help.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no trivial way to output a floating point value from a DOS assembly program. Look for an existing float-to-text subroutine that you can copy.

Comment: Does your prof have office hours? Or a TA with office hours? Or an email address? You might have better luck there...

Comment: Converting IEEE floating point to string accurately and efficiently is still actively being researched. Here's [a 2018 paper that shows a 3x improvement over what was previously known](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3192366.3192369).

Comment: Is there any other way to display a floating point number without having to convert it to a string?

Comment: Depending on your requirements you could try to convert it to fixed point and use integer instructions. Unfortunately `tan` covers all the reals so you would in general have to print very small and large floats as well ... as I said, depends on requirements.

Comment: You don't need to repeatedly load and pop `x`. You can use `fmul x` or `fmul ST(0), ST(1)`. Optionally, you can store x^3 for calculating x^5 and x^7. For the output, `fstp` put the float in memory but `int 21h` prints a string. What you need is `FISTTP` and a loop to print the sign and each digits. If you need the fraction, use `fsub` and `fabs` to calculate the diff between `tan` and the result of `FISTTP`. But before you try, check your lecture notes. I would be really really surprised if the lecturer hadn't taught you how to print floats.

Comment: @Patryk: *something* has to convert it to a string in order to get something that can be displayed to humans, whether that's a hex-dump of the bit-pattern or whether that's ASCII text that represents the value in decimal (like `1.234`).  If you don't want to write code yourself to do it, you'd have to call a library function (like `printf("%f\n", foo)` in C).  DOS interrupts don't include FP->string conversion so you'd need to find an appropriate library, e.g. one that comes with a C compiler.

Comment: @Patryk By definition, no.